# convert roman numerals using for loop

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find what am I missing? if I try 3 it will return II instead of III same thing if it's 8 it will return VII instead of VIII.
I just added the 8 and 3 in my numerals variable

```
    VIII: 8,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    III: 3,
    I: 1,
```

but if you guys have any suggestion to fix it without adding it in the numerals that would be great

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  //values of the numbers
  let numerals = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };
  //passing the new values of the new numbers to convert into numerals
  let newNumeral = "";
  //checking the values of numerals objects
  for (let i in numerals) {
    //using the j variable of num, if the num is still greater than the numerals index it will increment the key to the variable newNumerals and stop the loop, it will subtract the num to the values of numerals .
    for (let j= 0; j <= num; j++ ){
      if(num >= numerals[i]) {
        newNumeral += i;
        num -= numerals[i];
       
      }  
    }
  }
  //return to newNumerals to see the new value.
 return newNumeral;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(3));
```

Comment: Why are you looping `num` times in the inner loop? That makes no sense.

Comment: anyway the issue with your code is that num is mutating. if you make a copy of num and the run the inner for loop on that should work.for example `let numCopy = num;
    for (let j= 0; j <= numCopy; j++ ){...`

Comment: Yes I tried it, it works! Thank you

Comment: @Barmar I thought that by looping it inside it will compare the values of numerals to num. Do you mean I dont need the for loop with `j` variable to solve it?

Comment: Right. If `num` is 100, that will iterate 101 times. That's not needed to produce one character `C`.

Comment: @Barmar I see. I did try removing the for loop inside it but it keeps messing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `for` loop is a bit weird, you don't use j for anything.

You can replace that and the `if` inside with a simpler `while` loop.

```js
//values of the numbers
  let numerals = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };

const convertToRoman = (num) => {
  let newNumeral = "";

  for (let i in numerals) {
    while (num >= numerals[i]) {
      newNumeral += i;
      num -= numerals[i];
    }  
  }

  return newNumeral;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(3));
console.log(convertToRoman(1990));
```

Comment: Yes I saw that solution but I want to try if it is possible to solve it in for loop. I thought I used it right to check the value of numerals and num

Comment: `for (; num >= numerals[i]; )`